# Nodejs: Sequelize and json

Tags: node.js, json

With NodeJs and Sequelize I want to extract records from db and obtain a json string
What can I do to obtain a json string like

```
table1_r1
    table2_r1
    table2_r2
table1_r2
    table2_r5
    table2_r6
table1_r3
    table2_r3
    table2_r4
table1_r4
    table2_r8
```

where for each record of table1 I have its records of table2

Comment: What have you tried so far? What links the tables together? This question is extremely broad.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an object with arrays:

```
{
    "table1_r1": ["table2_r1", "table2_r2"],
    "table1_r2": ["table2_r5", "table2_r6"],
    "table1_r3": ["table2_r3", "table2_r4"],
    "table1_r4": ["table2_r8"]
}
```

Comment: obviously, but how can I do to build an object like this using sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

my tables schema are the next

```
CREATE TABLE `settore` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_dirigente` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_persona_settore` (`id_dirigente`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_persona_settore` FOREIGN KEY (`id_dirigente`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;

CREATE TABLE `ruolo` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `descrizione` VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `dsbreve` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=11
;

CREATE TABLE `persona` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cognome` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nome` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `titolo` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_ruolo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `matricola` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `telefonoFisso` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `telefonoMobile` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `breveFisso` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `breveMobile` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_persona_ruolo` (`id_ruolo`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_persona_ruolo` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ruolo`) REFERENCES `ruolo` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=285
;

CREATE TABLE `struttura` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_settore` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_responsabile` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_struttura_settore` (`id_settore`),
    INDEX `idx_struttura_responsabile` (`id_responsabile`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_struttura_responsabile` FOREIGN KEY (`id_responsabile`) REFERENCES `persona` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_struttura_settore` FOREIGN KEY (`id_settore`) REFERENCES `settore` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
```

how can I create tables mapping with sequelize? are there some tools to build mapping objects automatically

the fielde id_dirigente of settore is a fk to persona

```
Settore.belongsTo(Persona);
```

but how do I declare that the id_dirigente must match id of table persona?

```
class Ruolo extends Model {}
Ruolo.init({
      // attributes
        id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true , allowNull: false},
        descrizione: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
        dsbreve: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
}, 
{
  sequelize,
  freezeTableName: true,
  timestamps: false, // così non cerca i campi createdAt e updatedAt
  modelName: 'ruolo'
// options
} 
);  

class Persona extends Model {}
Persona.init({
  // attributes
    id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true , allowNull: false},
    titolo: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    cognome: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    nome: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    username: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    id_ruolo: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    email: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    telefonoFisso: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    telefonoMobile: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    breveFisso: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    breveMobile: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
  }, 
  {
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false, // così non cerca i campi createdAt e updatedAt
    modelName: 'persona'
  // options
  } 
);  

Persona.belongsTo(Ruolo);

class Settore extends Model {}
Settore.init({
    // attributes
    id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true , allowNull: false},
    nome: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    id_dirigente: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER}
  }, 
  {
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false, // così non cerca i campi createdAt e updatedAt
    modelName: 'settore'
  // options
  } 
);   

Settore.belongsTo(Persona);
```

Comment: Please don't put your question in the answer section. Update your question accordingly and remove this answer.